# can't use openpyxl even though it's installed

Tags: python, pycharm, openpyxl

I used the pip method to install openpyxl, now the command prompt gives me this:

```
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in c:\users\(my name)\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (3.0.10)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in c:\users\(my name)\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)
```

However, when I tried to use openpyxl in Pycharm (from openpyxl import Workbook), it gave me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/(my name)/PycharmProjects/(project)/(file).py", line 3, in <module>
    from openpyxl import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

What happened, how can I make it work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  This type of issue is more or less related to you using a different python binary.  Which python binary is PyCharm set to use?

Comment: Did you download with pip inside pycharm's module tab?